# I need to poll only unprocessed message from kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

**Scenario:**
I've a kafka consumer which polls message from kafka every second from the beginning. Message contains timestamp field so that I can filter only those messages which has time is equal to current time. Intially it is working fine but now in kafka I have lot of messages and not able to poll all the messages.

once the timestamp field from message is equal to current timestamp then  I'll process it, so I don't want to poll that message again next time.

Is it possible to update the message in the kafka so that once the message is processed, I'll add one boolean to it(say "processed: true") and poll only the messages which has 'processed: false' ?

or *Can you suggest anyother approach?*

**Note:** Messages with the timestamp field is not in sequential manner. The last message or the message in mid will process then next time I don't want to poll the last/mid message. Also I've 12 partitions and 12 consumers to poll the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka records are immutable, and the brokers do not know anything about your individual consumer processing logic; the consumer only tells the brokers what offset it wants to store, nothing else.

You can "filter" events by sending to a brand-new topic when records have "exceeded some timestamp", then "process" them later. However, you will have to constantly seek backwards, on some time window, in the topic to see "old" events that have not "triggered" yet.

This is not recommended, and instead, you can dump all events to some database table as you see them, then use some filter such as `SELECT * WHERE timestamp BETWEEN {last_execution} AND NOW()`. You can also chose to store extra metadata here like `status = PROCESSED / ERROR`, retry counts, actually do batch-deletes from this database, etc.

> every second from the beginning

Definitely not recommended. There is no guarantee you will reach the end of the topic within 1 second for large topics.

> once the timestamp field from message is equal to current timestamp then I'll process it

Don't do this, for the above reason. Otherwise, you'll lose time-accuracy and miss events.

> don't want to poll that message again next time

If you seek to the beginning, or just before that offset at all, you're going to poll it. There is no workaround. You need to maintain some external state of what you've seen already or not.